# Show actual database data when browsing through dataset (FireDac, FDQuery)

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am writing a program accessing a multi-user database using the FireDac components.

I have a table "Customers" where i store some customer data.

The users should always see the current actual data that is stored in the database.

**The problem:**

Imagine there are 2 users (User A and User B) logged it.
So my application is opened 2 times on 2 different pcs.

Both logged in at the same time and see the same data records.

User A decides to edit the first customers name from "John Doe" to "Tom Smith" and saves (`.Post`) it to the database.

The new name is now stored in the database correctly.

User B is still viewing customer #1 and doesn't see the changes made (that's fine because he didn't browse or refresh this data record after it got changed).
But if User B browses to customer #2 and then back to #1 he still sees the old data ("John  Doe" instead of "Tom Smith").

[image: before] [image: after]

--

So if a user browses through the dataset he sees the data values from when the query fetched them.

--

**Current solution:**

The "AfterScroll" / "BeforeScroll" event is triggered each time the dataset "shows" a different record.

So what i did is call FDQuery1.Refresh inside these events to make sure the actual data is displayed.

--

Is modifiying said events the "correct" solution for my problem or is there a better way accomplish what i want?

I hope you understand my problem and thanks for reading.

Comment: Calculare the Cuostomer Id when saving.

Comment: Its generally  a bad idea to call .Refresh within a Before/AfterScroll event.  Apart from the fact that it doesn't fit with the TDataSet internal model of its state and events, the scroll events are called far too frequently to be useful.  Try continuously pressing the Down key in a grid.  Instead, do the refresh in an OnTimer event or, much better, do it in a background thread.

Comment: Btw, what database server back-end are you using?

Comment: @MartynA I'm currently using Oracle but also want to support MSSQL and MySql.

Comment: Well, MJN has given you a good answer, and if you're using FireDAC, you can use its event alerter for MS SQL and Oracle.  Problem is, MySQL has no support for FireDAC event alerters, so if you want a common solution for all three, you'll need something else.  If the clients will all be Windows PCs on a LAN, consider a DIY alert system using MS Message Queue; not sure how to implement that for MySQL, though.

Comment: ADO is capeable of doing this task via Recordset.Resync. not sure this could be done with Firedac.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate notification mechanism which broadcasts events such as 'new order arrived', 'customer record modified' etc. to all interested clients.

Some databases contain built-in support for this technique (for example [Firebird events](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=102)). It avoids frequent reloading of data, and so it can minimize network traffic and improve application responsiveness.

See also: [Database Alerts (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29)

> The DBMS alert refers to a database notification or alert sent by a
>   database trigger or stored procedure with the purpose of notifying a
>   database client about some events at database side.

But you are not limited to these FireDac specific alerts. You could build your own, database-independent, notification system between clients with many other ways and protocols such as Sockets, HTTP, MQTT, STOMP etc.